# Java AWT - repaint() method thread scheduling

Tags: java, applet, awt

What I am looking to do is have the user to be able to change perspectives from a `KeyListener`. If the user hits the specified key, than the perspective should change. Any ideas?

Even if I override the methods they still do not work. I have also tried `KeyAdapter`

```
package com.development.gameOne.environment.component;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.development.gameOne.environment.applet.drawing.Perspective;
import com.development.gameOne.environment.applet.perspectives.p1.FirstPerspective;
import com.development.gameOne.environment.applet.perspectives.p2.SecondPerspective;

public class Component extends Applet implements KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Dimension size = new Dimension(1280, 720);

    private ArrayList<Perspective> perspectives = new ArrayList<Perspective>();
    private boolean running = true;
    private boolean switchPerspective = false;

    public Component() {
        setPreferredSize(size);
        loadPerspectives();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setVisible(true);
        start();
    }

    private void loadPerspectives() {
        perspectives.add(new FirstPerspective());
        perspectives.add(new SecondPerspective());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Component();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        while (running) {
            for (Perspective p : perspectives) {
                System.out.println(p.getPerspective());
                while (!switchPerspective) {
                    System.out.println("Rendering");
                    p.start(g);
                    sleep(100);
                }
                switchPerspective = false;
            }
            sleep(10);
        }
    }

    public static void sleep(int renderSpeed) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(renderSpeed);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT:
            System.out.println("KeyPressed");
            switchPerspective = true;
            break;
        }
    }



    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

The program runs, but doesn't switch perspectives. I cannot seem to get the `KeyListener`
to work at all. I really have no idea what to do.

Comment: I'd hate to disillusion you, but this question has nothing to do with Swing and is pure AWT

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec by your instructor, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT components rather than Swing?  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon AWT.

Comment: Thank you, and I didn't mean to tag swing if I did, but how is java 8, is it a lot better than swing? Should I just learn that instead?  @MadProgrammer

Comment: @JoeD Not really taking advantage of Java 8 at the moment, but the diamond operators on generics and try with resources are a welcome inclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the issue is with your `KeyListener`, but is with your paint process

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    while (running) {
        for (Perspective p : perspectives) {
            System.out.println(p.getPerspective());
            while (!switchPerspective) {
                System.out.println("Rendering");
                p.start(g);
                sleep(100);
            }
            switchPerspective = false;
        }
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

This will block the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from ever been able to process new events coming into the system

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for details about how painting works in AWT.

The (simple) solution, in this case, would be to provide a other `Thread` which handles the timing between updates and simple call `repaint` when you want the UI updated.

A better solution would be take take advantage of the a `BufferStrategy` instead.  It still require a `Thread`, but stops you from breaking the painting chain.

As a side note.  AWT `Applet`s are woefully out-of-date and were replaced by `JApplet` before 2000.  Having said that, I would recommend against using applets at all, as they have enough problems which only increases the difficulty of starting development and focus on something like a `JPanel` added to an instance of a `JFrame` instead.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

I'd also drop the use of `KeyListener` as soon as you can in favour of Swing's Key bindings API.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

I'd also avoid calling your applet `Component`, there already is a class called `Component` and this is just going to confuse matters...

And applets, definitely, should not have a `main` method.  They are expected to be loaded by the browser directly and have a different, defined, life cycle.